# Pass Bool() value between dfferent swift targets

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, boolean, custom-keyboard

I'm trying to create a settings view controller in my container app for my customKeyboard for iOS8 in Swift. I have create a Bool() and I got right what I need by that, but now i need to get the Keyboard target checking the bool value and I can't import the other swift file..

I've this code:

**ViewControllerSettings.swift**:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Switch1: UISwitch!

var dotOn = Bool()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("dotOn") == true {

        Switch1.setOn(true, animated: true)

    } else {

        Switch1.setOn(false, animated: true)

    }


  @IBAction func backSave(sender: UIButton) {

    if Switch1.on == true {


        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "dotOn")

    } else {

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "dotOn")

    }
  }
```

And it works great! But in my **KeyboardViewController.swift** in another target of the App I have in the viewDidAppear(animated: true) :

```
  if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("dotOn") == true {

let bSelector : Selector = "dotAfterSpace:"
    let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:   bSelector)
    doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    space.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)

 } else { }
```

And this function without the "if" works well... what should I do?

---

After some advice I wrote this code... but where am I wrong?

In **KeyboardViewController.swift**:

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
     var otherController = ViewControllerSettings()

override func viewDidAppear(animated:Bool) {
   super.viewDidAppear(animated)

   KeyboardViewController().otherController = ViewControllerSettings()

    if otherController.dotOn {

        let bSelector : Selector = "dotAfterSpace:"
        let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: bSelector)
        doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        space.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)

    } else { }

    let aSelector : Selector = "spacePressed:"
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    space.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}
```

In **ViewControllerSettings.swift**:

```
class ViewControllerSettings: UIViewController {

 var dotOn = Bool()
```

Comment: if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("dotOn") {...}

Comment: there is no need for "== true"

Comment: same applies for Switch.on == true

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus it doesn't work.. :/

Comment: It will not solve your problem it is just not needed

Comment: And a final one (also not related to your problem): `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(Switch1.on, forKey: "dotOn")` will do without any if/else.

Comment: And of course: `Switch1.setOn(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("dotOn"), animated: true)`

Comment: And a very last remark: use lower case letter for vars (as per convention). Upper case only for types.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Thank You! But related to my problem nothing?

Comment: Well, if the two view controllers are in the same app then why not pass the value as a parameter?

Comment: @ThomasKilian well... I don't know how to do that.. I've searched also some weeks ago but I didn't found anything about assigning a parameter to a value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a property on both sides of your controllers:

```
class ViewController1:<CtrlType1> {
   var otherController:<CtrlType2>

   func doSomething() {
     if otherController.sharedBool { .... }
   }
 }

class ViewController2:<CtrlType2> {
   var sharedBool = false

 }
```

In the place where you create both instances (or where they have been created by IB) add

```
 viewController1.otherController = viewController2
```

This way you can use the bool in both instances.

Another approach would be to use a singleton, but for a simple bool that would be overkill.

Comment: with <CtrlType2/1>you mean the type of the two controller? I have a UIViewController and a UIInputViewController... It's ok? Because it doesn't work..

Comment: The types in angle brackets must be replaced by real ones you use. In OSX it would be NSViewController.

Comment: But it says me that < and > are not prefix unary operators and doesn't read the property..

Comment: And if I put instead of <CtrlType2> the name of my UIVIewController: var otherController = ViewControllerSettings() it doesn't do nothing when running...

Comment: Of course not. You must assign it from outside. This way you create a new instance.

Comment: As I said: `var otherController = ViewControllerSettings()` creates a new instance which is not your other view controller. You need to assign it in ViewControllerSettings or from the controlling class.